# Auto-resizing QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, widget, resize, qt5, qstackedwidget

I have a class `StackedWidget` which inherits from `QStackedWidget`. The standard behaviour of `QStackedWidget` is that it adopts the size of its biggest element. What I want to do is force it to resize to its current element. I have already tried a couple of solutions found here and none of them work including e.g. setting size policies or calling `hide()` on all the widgets that go out of sight.

I think problem may reside in two possibilities:
1. Something is terribly wrong with `StackedWidget`. 2. The problem of resizing does not pertain directly to `StackedWidget` but to some layout or another widget that `StackedWidget` is nested in.

1. Concerning the first possibility, here I provide the `StackedWidget` class.

Please take a look at what my `StackedWidget`'s declaration looks like:

```
  class StackedWidget : public QStackedWidget
  {
    Q_OBJECT
    private:
      QComboBox* widgetChooser = nullptr;
    public:
      StackedWidget(QWidget* parent) : QStackedWidget(parent) {}
      void setWidgetChooser(QComboBox* widgetChooser);
      void addWidget(QWidget* widget);
    private:
      void makeConnection();
    signals:
    public slots:
      void setCurrentIndex(const int& index);
  };
```

Here goes the definition:

```
    void StackedWidget::setWidgetChooser(QComboBox* widgetChooser)
    {
      if (widgetChooser == nullptr) throw RuntimeError("widgetChooser is nullptr");
      this->widgetChooser = widgetChooser;
      makeConnection();
    }

    void StackedWidget::addWidget(QWidget* widget)
    {
      widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
      QStackedWidget::addWidget(widget);
    }

    void StackedWidget::makeConnection()
    {
      connect(widgetChooser, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    }

    void StackedWidget::setCurrentIndex(const int& index)
    {
      qDebug() << "Index changed to " << index;
      QWidget* pWidget = widget(index);
      Q_ASSERT(pWidget);
      QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget(pWidget);
      pWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
      pWidget->adjustSize();
      adjustSize();
    }
```

2. Concering the second possibility, here goes how I use `StackedWidget`.

```
void SchemaWidget::TempBuildAlt(const SchemaElement* son, QVBoxLayout* parentLayout)
  {
    if (auto schemaAlternative = dynamic_cast<const SchemaAlternatives*>(son))
    {
      QComboBox* widgetBox = BuildWidgetChooserBox(schemaAlternative);
      StackedWidget* stackedWidget = BuildStackedWidget(schemaAlternative);
      stackedWidget->setWidgetChooser(widgetBox);

      QHBoxLayout* boxLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
      boxLayout->addWidget(new QLabel(schemaAlternative->Name, this));
      boxLayout->addWidget(widgetBox);

      QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
      layout->addLayout(boxLayout);
      layout->addWidget(stackedWidget);

      parentLayout->addLayout(layout);
    } else throw RuntimeError("Cannot cast son to SchemaAlternatives.");
  }

  QComboBox* SchemaWidget::BuildWidgetChooserBox(const SchemaAlternatives* schema)
  {
    QComboBox* alternativesBox = new QComboBox(this);
    QStringListModel* listModel = new QStringListModel(this);
    QStringList list;
    for (int i = 1; i <= schema->Sons.High(); ++i)
    {
      if (const SchemaTree* son = dynamic_cast<const SchemaTree*>(schema->Sons(i).Get()))
      {
        list << son->Name;
      }
      else throw RuntimeError("Son cannot be cast to SchemaTree.");
    }
    listModel->setStringList(list);
    alternativesBox->setModel(listModel);
    return alternativesBox;
  }

  StackedWidget* SchemaWidget::BuildStackedWidget(const SchemaAlternatives* schema)
  {
    StackedWidget* stackedWidget = new StackedWidget(this);
    for (int i = 1; i <= schema->Sons.High(); ++i)
    {
      if (const SchemaTree* alternativeSon = dynamic_cast<const SchemaTree*>(schema->Sons(i).Get()))
      {
        QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);
        QVBoxLayout* widgetLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        BuildWidget(alternativeSon, widgetLayout);
        widget->setLayout(widgetLayout);
        stackedWidget->addWidget(widget);
      }
      else throw RuntimeError("Son could not be cast to SchemaTree.");
    }
    return stackedWidget;
  }
```

I want to say thanks in advance to anyone who will be willing to spend some time on my problem. I do appreciate it. Thanks. You're great.

Comment: Have you tried just overriding [`QWidget::sizeHint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) in your `StackedWidget` class?  Have it return the size hint associated with the current widget.

Comment: I have overriden it and it did nothing. 
Is it just a matter of overriding or do I have to call it somewhere? I presume it is done automatically somewhere without programmer's influence but I just want to have it clear.

Comment: Yes, it would be called automatically by Qt's layout management code.